# Was Mr. Nobody a profitable investment?

Tags: production, mr-nobody

According to IMDb, the budget of [*Mr. Nobody* (2009)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0485947) was $47 million. However the gross from opening weekend was only $1,612, second month $3,600, even worldwide the gross profit is low and it doesn't sum up with the original estimated budget.

As per 2017, was *Mr. Nobody* a profitable investment, or did it not earn enough profit to cover the total estimated costs?

Comment: Determining profitability of any movie is problematical at best...impossible and opinion based at worst.

Comment: Also, box office takings is not the same as profit...the theater takes a big chunk.

Comment: @Paulie_D depends on the film. First week or two, the theater generally gets very little... 10% or less. This is why popcorn is so expensive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Worldwide box office was $2.33M on a budget of $47M.  I'd say, considering the movie is somewhat obscure, it will most likely never recoup its expenditures even after home video sales/TV broadcast rights are taken into account.  You can "buy" it from IMDB for $2.99, but that's gonna take a **lot** of sales to recover the $44+M difference between budget and box office.